# Updating the cloned element values in db without deleting the Previous cloned field records

Tags: sql, ruby

I have cloned the "div" which containing 3 fields. While Im updating those values in the database, im deleting the earlier values and replacing these values using the id. How can i update the column values without deleting earlier record values ?

```
@pre_data=MgMultiSelect.where(:mg_details_id=>params[:id])

@pre_data.each do |select|
  select.is_deleted=1
  select.save
end

@selected_data=params[:team_id_new]

if @selected_data.present?

  for i in 0...@selected_data.length

    @update_data=MgMultiSelect.new()
    @update_data.team_id_new=@selected_data[i]
    @update_data.mg_details_id=@task_data.id
    @update_data.is_deleted=0
    @update_data.save

  end

end
```

Model :

```
class CreateMgMultiSelects < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
  create_table :mg_multi_selects do |t|
     t.string :team_id_new
     t.integer :mg_details_id
     t.boolean :is_deleted
     t.timestamps
    end
 end
end
```

Comment: Can you provide some kind of code snippet to describe the issue?

Comment: here i took the reference column as "is_deleted" and setting it into false. Im retrieving the records where the "is_deleted" is true. Instead , i want to modify the already existed record's values

Comment: is the code snippet is enough or i have to append a bit more? @JohnBargman

Comment: I'm afraid I'm a little out of my depth on this one, I'm learning Ruby myself - I hope someone else can assist you though.

Comment: Oh,thats fine . Anyway , thanks for the response :) @JohnBargman

Comment: how can i  make this question visible in the "Newly Added Questions" list .Any suggestions ????

Comment: Can you share models and their attributes you are using in above function and make it more understanding ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try it this way :

```
@pre_data=MgMultiSelect.where(:mg_details_id=>params[:id])

@selected_data=params[:team_id_new]
if params[:team_id_new].present?

  params[:team_id_new].each do |id|
   obj = @pre_data.where(:team_id_new => id).first
   if obj.present?
    obj.update_attributes(:mg_details_id => @task_data.id,:is_deleted => 0 )
   end
  end
end
```